# What is JavaScript `pass`

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

I was reading on MDN on mobile, so maybe I've missed something obvious. I've seen in this code the method `pass` being used.

```
var allPass = true;
var i, j;

top:
for (i = 0; items.length; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < tests.length; i++)
    if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])){
      allPass = false;
      break top;
     }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Googling "mdn pass" got me nowhere. What is pass?

Comment: I think it's just an example, with a fictive method `pass` of a fictive prototype.

Comment: _“What is pass?”_ – a method of the `test` objects that the example works on according to description. Those are not _specific_ objects and methods here – they are simply used to provide a little context to have an example for `continue` that _could_ be part o a real use case. Replace them with an object `foo` that has a method `bar` if you like …

Comment: This is sample code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass is a method of an array element (some kind of test function)